# How do I implement autocomplete textbox using asp.net mvc, javascript,cache, ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2005, c#-4.0

I need implement Auto complete text box,values getting from database (Server) using Asp.Net MVC3, using javascript not with jQuery. So please try help me with source.

I am using ASP.Net MVC3.

Comment: use a plugin like jquery UI autocomplete

Comment: you can try using html5 datalist for the autocomplete text field. And just use your knowledge on asp.net to fetch the records from the database

Comment: @3nigma: Hard to do with the restriction "not with jQuery"...

Comment: @EricJ. AH! i should have read the question carefully ..

Answer (score 1):

For this there is jquery autocomplete is there.
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete
what you need to do is just write a jquery code.
suppose this is the text box in your view page.

< input type="text" id="AutoComplete" value="" />

write a jquery for this textbox.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#AutoComplete").keypress(function () {
            var title = $("#AutoComplete").val();
            var availableTags = [];
            if (title.length == 3) {
                $.get("/Wk/GetTitle/" + title, function (data) {
                    var arr = jQuery.makeArray(data.split(','));
                    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                        availableTags.push(arr[i]);
                    }
                    $("#AutoComplete").autocomplete({
                        source: availableTags
                    });
```

//                        $("#AutoComplete").select();
                    });

```
            }
        });
    });
```

This will call action method using ajax and this action method return the list to show.
here get  title is the action method.
the controller action code is

```
     [HttpGet]
    public StringBuilder GetTitle(string inputString)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        List<string> title = new List<string>();
        int i = 0;
        string slug = RouteData.Values.Values.ElementAt(2).ToString();
        title = pageBL.GetTitleAutocomplete(slug);

        for (i = 0; i <= title.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (i != title.Count -1 )
                sb = sb.Append(title.ElementAt(i) + ",");
            else
                sb = sb.Append(title.ElementAt(i) );
        }
        return sb;
    }
```

This code will help you
ask me if you get any prob

Comment: Actually i need implement using only Javascript not with Jquery could you please help on that

Comment: i have given you the whole code you dont need to do anything new just edit acc to your requirement

Comment: i dont want Use Jquery .only javascript,Ajax..please help

Answer (score 0):

**In View:-**

```
<input type="text" id="txtRemark" name="txtRemark" class="form-control" placeholder="Remark"> 


<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
$("#txtRemark").autocomplete({     
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/ControllerName/AutoCompleteRemark",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: { remark: request.term },
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) { 
                                return { label: item.VCEHRemark, value: item.VCEHRemark };
                            }))
                        }
                    })
                },
                messages: {
                    noResults: "", results: ""
                }
            });
```

})

**In Controller:-**

```
public JsonResult AutoCompleteRemark(string remark)
        { 
            var result = db.tablename.Where(p => p.VCEHRemark.Contains(remark)).Select(p => new { p.VCEHRemark });
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```